# android- make home screen widget visible

Tags: android, android-widget

After long pres on homescreen I am able to found my widget in widget list but, when i click on that widget it is not visible in Android 2.3 but visible in 4.2. Can anyone tell me how to make it visible in 2.3 also?

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main" android:updatePeriodMillis="0" android:minHeight="90dp" android:minWidth="144dp">
```

Comment: can you illustrate more not getting what you want to say .. or paste something what you code for it and at what point you are getting error.

Comment: please check the solution and reply is it useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

if i am not wrong please go in xml view and make visibility to visible.

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

Comment: actually widget is getting added in android 4.2 but not in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change 
android:minHeight="150dp" android:minWidth="200dp". Can't believable..!